# NLP Frameworks for converting natural language to database queries

Tags: nlp

Are there any frameworks available,especially open source ones which can interpret natural language and convert it into RDBMS or NOSQL database queries?

Comment: Have you looked into IBM Watson or Microsoft Cognitive Services?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Quepy](https://github.com/machinalis/quepy)!
It is a python framework to transform natural language questions to queries in a database query language.

As of June 2020 Quepy provides support for [Sparql](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) and [MQL](http://www.freebase.com/) query languages.

Comment: at least a link would be nice, also more details appreciated: e.g. what `query language`?